# How do I programmatically scroll to the end of a Flex Spark Textarea when a new line is added?

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

The old method for the mx:TextArea no longer works. Specifically:

```
myMxTextArea.verticalScrollPosition = myMxTextArea.maxVerticalScrollPosition;
```

I've found this method for Spark but seems a bit kludgy:

```
mySparkTA.scrollToRange(mySparkTA.text.length-1, mySparkTA.text.length);
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have

```
<s:TextArea id="ta" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

The following will work:

```
ta.scroller.verticalScrollBar.value = ta.scroller.verticalScrollBar.maximum;
```

No need to wrap the TextArea in a Scroller component.

Comment: do not forget about validateNow()  else UI may bot be refreshed

Answer (score 2):

That is how you do with with a spark textarea, but you could always try to wrap it in a Scroller component and not have the textarea itself bother with scrolling:

```
<s:Scroller id="scroller">
   <s:TextArea id="ta" width="100%" height="100%" />
</s:Scroller>
```

Then doing this in AS:

```
scroller.verticalScrollBar.value = scroller.verticalScrollBar.maximum;
```

There's no other *easy* way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. This may have worked at one point but in the latest SDK 4.6 I get this error, "'spark.components.TextArea' is not assignable to the default property, 'viewport', of type 'spark.core.IViewport'." Also, what event do you call the AS code on?

Comment: Yeah, it probably doesn't work anymore.  You'll need to wrap the TextArea with a Group or something.  I'm not too sure what you mean which event you call it on...

Answer (score 1):

The spark TextArea has an "appendText" method
This appends the text and scrolls automatically down to the line added..

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:TextArea id="consoleTextArea" 
            change="consoleTextArea_changeHandler(event)"
            valueCommit="consoleTextArea_valueCommitHandler(event)"
            updateComplete="scrollToTheBottom()"
            />
```

And then in ActionScript:

```
        protected function consoleTextArea_valueCommitHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
            scrollToTheBottom();
        }

        protected function consoleTextArea_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void {
            scrollToTheBottom()
        }

        public function scrollToTheBottom():void {
            var scrollBar:VScrollBar = consoleTextArea.scroller.verticalScrollBar;
            scrollBar.value = scrollBar.maximum;
            consoleTextArea.validateNow();

            if (scrollBar.value != scrollBar.maximum) {
                scrollBar.value = scrollBar.maximum;
                consoleTextArea.validateNow();
            }
        }
```

You might need to put the if statement in a loop for a few iterations or until the value matches or is close to the maximum.

**Update**: Added listener for updateComplete event. This may get in the way of someone typing but may work fine for this use case.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It works successfully for me.